# Intent Service with Bluetooth - Android Studio

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an app which uses Bluetooth connection - so far - to send and receive data from Arduino.
I was using an Activity and now I'm trying to switch to Fragments, so I can share data between then.
The problem: the Bluetooth part of the code can't be copied in all fragments, nor stay in the old activity. Which means that I need to find a way to keep the same Bluetooth connection active in whatever fragment open so they can communicate and share data between themselves.
I was wondering: what is the best approach to that? IntentService Class? Creating a whole interface just for the Bluetooth parameters?

```
package br.com.fespy.fespybluetooth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class NavDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //STATEMENTS DECLARATIONS

    Switch switch1, switch2, switch3;
    boolean btState = false;
    boolean test = true;
    private static String MAC = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECTION_BT = 2;

    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = null;
    BluetoothDevice myBluetoothDevice = null;
    BluetoothSocket myBluetoothSocket = null;

    UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


    NavDrawer.ConnectedThread connectedThread;

    public void startService (View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Bluetooth.class);
        startService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Back up to their brains.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //HOME TITLE

        setTitle("");

        //DISPLAYS THE FESPY LOGO
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.fespy2);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //SWITCH BUTTONS
        switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        switch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        switch3 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch3);


        //LOADS OF BLUETOOTH SETTINGS

        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device disconnected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) //CHECK FOR BLUETOOTH CONNECTION
        {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }


        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    if (btState) {
                      connectedThread.write("1");

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switch1.setChecked(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (btState) {
                        connectedThread.write("0");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switch1.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        switch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    if (btState) {
                        connectedThread.write("3");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switch2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (btState) {
                        connectedThread.write("2");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switch2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        switch3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    if (btState) {
                        connectedThread.write("5");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switch3.setChecked(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (btState) {
                        connectedThread.write("4");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switch3.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.header_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) //SETTINGS FROM NAV BAR
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
        }


        //BLUETOOTH CONNECTION BUTTON

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.btConnect: {
                if (btState) {
                    try {
                        myBluetoothSocket.close();
                        btState = false;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth disconnected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (IOException error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Intent openList = new Intent(NavDrawer.this, AvailableDevices.class);
                    startActivityForResult(openList, REQUEST_CONNECTION_BT);
                }
            }



        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth activated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The app needs a bluetooth connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_CONNECTION_BT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    MAC = data.getExtras().getString(AvailableDevices.MAC_ADDRESS);
                    myBluetoothDevice = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);

                    try {
                        myBluetoothSocket = myBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                        myBluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) myBluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(myBluetoothDevice, 1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        myBluetoothSocket.connect();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        btState = true;

                        connectedThread = new NavDrawer.ConnectedThread(myBluetoothSocket);
                        connectedThread.start();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //connect.setChecked(false); <<removed from the code
                        btState = false;
                    }
                } else //missclick
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //connect.setChecked(false); <<removed from the code
                }

        }
    }

    class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    //   .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(String sentData) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = sentData.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you mantain the connection logic in the Activity and have the fragments communicate with the activity to get the information they need and/or to exchange information with the other fragments?

Comment: Because I can't find a way to intent boolean values without starting a new Activity, and consequently, leaving the Fragment page.

Comment: I've read the code you posted but I still can't see the connection betwee the problem you mention about doing intent booleans and using fragments in the activity.  Can you provide a specific example of what you are trying to do or which part is the one won't work?

Comment: I want to control the written values through a Fragment screen. To do so, I need to enter in one of the conditional structures present in the Activity: the ones containing "connectedThread.write("1");" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:
In your main activity you create the fragments.

You manage the fragments using the SupportFragmentManager showing / hiding them according to your needs.

MainActivity can call methods on the fragments so the down part of the communication is done through the public methods of each fragment.

For the up going part of the communication, from the fragment to the activity, each fragment will define an interface that MainActivity has to implement.

The interface defines what methods (callbacks) MainActivity will be listening on each Fragment.

When the Fragment is created, after the activity is already created, the fragment sets the MainActivity as its listener.

When the fragment receives an event that needs to be forwarded to the Main Activity it will do it calling is corresponding method defined in the interface on its listener and MainActivity will react to that by doing something or forwarding the evenet to another fragment you define.

In this simplified example I am only using one fragment to show the way it works. You will add Fragments as needed each one with its own interface for callbacks.

When you change the switch in the fragment, main activity will display a Toast with the current value.

For your problem, you are getting the boolean value in the main activity so you can hadle it from there as you are doing today.

Main Activity Layout - so_main_activity_43709698.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragments_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layout so_fragment_43709698_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch 1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity SO_43709698.java

```
package com.somepackage.so_43709698;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SO_43709698 extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment_43709698_1.Fragment_43709698_1_Listener {

    Fragment_43709698_1 fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.so_main_activity_43709698);

        //FrameLayout fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        fragment1 = new Fragment_43709698_1();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragments_container,fragment1,"Fragment1")
                .show(fragment1)
                .commit();

    }

    //This is a callback from fragent1 used when fragment one wants to send a "message" to MainActivity
    //You can implement as many as you need.
    @Override
    public void onFragment_43709698_1_Switch1Change(boolean b) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Switch in Fragment 1 changed to: " + b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

Fragment 1 - Fragment_43709698_1.java

```
package com.somepackage.so_43709698;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class Fragment_43709698_1 extends Fragment {

    private Switch switch1;
    Fragment_43709698_1_Listener listener; //This will be the activity;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.so_fragment_43709698_1,container, false);
        switch1 = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                listener.onFragment_43709698_1_Switch1Change(b);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public int aMethodMainActivityCanCAll(String withSomeParameter){
        int aResultToMainActivity = 0;
        //MainActivity can call methods on the fragment to communicate things like
        //requesting some status, or pass throguh requests from other fragment.
        return aResultToMainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        listener = (Fragment_43709698_1_Listener) getActivity();
    }

    // In this interface you define what things the fragment can call on MainActivity to send it
    // "messages"
    public static interface Fragment_43709698_1_Listener{
        public void onFragment_43709698_1_Switch1Change(boolean b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I found a better way of doing so: using a public static boolean. I managed to change values inside the activity through the fragment BUT I couldn't listen for the boolean value change.

How am I supposed to check boolean value changes continuosly in the Activity?

Comment: See the solution I posted please. Your fragment sends events to the activity through the inteface it defines and making the activity implement it.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I only had a few problems implementing two interfaces, but I understand now. Thanks so much for the help, I'm still a beginner in Java/Android Studio.